# How to read multiple ".asc" raster files into R

Tags: r, gis, raster, spatial

I am trying to read multiple raster files into R so I can merge them into one, larger raster. Most of the files are ASCII files, though some are also TIF files.

I have tried the code from
[how to efficiently import multiple raster (.tif) files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746936/how-to-efficiently-import-multiple-raster-tif-files-into-r) but always receive error messages. I don't think it's to do with my files as I can read in the individual rasters one at a time and merge them fine. I'm ultimately dealing with hundreds of rasters though so need a way to process them all at once!

My example data is within the folder "HowesValley", which is a subfolder within my working directory.

When I input:

```
rastlist <- list.files(path = "/HowesValley", pattern='.asc', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
allrasters <- stack(rastlist)
```

I received the error

> Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

I have also tried:

```
rastlist <- list.files(path = "/HowesValley", pattern='.asc', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
allrasters <- lapply(rastlist, raster)
```

When I input

```
allrasters[[1]]
```

I get

> Error in allrasters[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

And when I input

```
plot(allrasters[[1]])
```

I get

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': subscript out of bounds

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found a method that works, in case anyone else runs into the same trouble!

I found the code I needed from https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/04/merge-asc-grids-with-r/ and [How to select multiple files with different extension in filelist in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773187/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-different-extension-in-filelist-in-r)

The code that works for me is:

```
library(rgdal)  
library(raster) 
setwd("D:/HowesValley") #set the working directory to the folder of interest
f <-list.files(path = ".",pattern = '.*\\.(tif|asc)$') #search for both .tif and .asc files
r <- lapply(f, raster) 
x <- do.call("merge",r) 
plot(x)
writeRaster(x,"HowesValleyComb.asc")
```